# Dynamic Object Initialization In JavaScript (just like PHP Reflection allows)?

Tags: php, javascript, design-patterns, reflection

Using Reflection in PHP I can dynamically create a object like so

```
$target = 'core_domain_Person';
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($target);
$obj = $reflect->newInstance();
```

I would like to replicate this same concept in JavaScript is there a way to do this out of the box? Or is there a way to replicate what Reflection is doing?

Comment: So I can create "view controller" objects based on the requested view. I don't know until runtime what the view is that is being requested.

Answer (score 6):

Your comment states:

> So I can create "view controller" objects based on the requested view. I don't know until runtime what the view is that is being requested.

I suggest keeping all views in a `views` object like so:

```
var views = {
    Foo: function() {},
    Bar: function() {},
    Dah: function() {}
};
```

Then, using bracket notation, you can access any view constructor:

```
var viewName = 'Foo';
var instanceOfView = new views[viewName];
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to do this! Should equal better performance I presume because I am not using eval().

Comment: Had to award @Universal the correct answer, because it was the first answer and the correct one for the question although your answer is a better solution :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SomeClass = function(arg1, arg2) {
    // ...
}

ReflectUtil.newInstance('SomeClass', 5, 7);
```

and implementation:

```
/**
 * @param strClass:
 *          class name
 * @param optionals:
 *          constructor arguments
 */
ReflectUtil.newInstance = function(strClass) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var clsClass = eval(strClass);
    function F() {
        return clsClass.apply(this, args);
    }
    F.prototype = clsClass.prototype;
    return new F();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that there is such a thing like a Reflection API in JavaScript. But in JavaScript there are no classes, anyway. Prototypes / functions are (first-class) objects like anything else. Might be annoying, but might also be very useful.

```
function create_instance(prototypeName) {
    eval('return new ' + prototypeName + '()');
```

Didn't test this, though.

Comment: I think you can do better:

function create_instance(prototypeName) {
    return new prototypeName();
}